# Issues with kudan camera while merged with native android application

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, kudan

I got a requirement where I need to merge the unity application with the native android app, I am using Kudan plugin in the unity 3d, I have exported the unity project to the android studio and created a new app in the android studio and merged the Unity app to native android app.Once I tested the build, everything is working fine except a camera(Kudan camera).Ar camera is not working as expected.I am using free ver of Kudan plugin.I have tested it without merging with the native app and it is working fine, in this case, If I merge unity app with native android app camera is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue, it will stop working camera torch of system too when you extending class `ARActivity` you can't able to access `setFlashMode()` method

Test this case in your phone by opening application and then trying to **on/off** torch.

Torch will be disable from system.

After then try with extending `Activity` class

recently i have ask same [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677759/android-kudan-extending-aractivity-will-stop-working-system-camera-torch-flas)

Comment: Are you using kudan plugin for ar , and tried combining kudan with native android app.If yes there is one more issue with kudan plugin ,When ever i have merged the kudan app with native app there is an error message 
 like "Failed to resolve kudan plugin" in android studio.Have you fixed this ?.If yes please help me in fixing this error.