# Android Kudan - Extending ARActivity will stop working system camera torch (Flash light)

Tags: android, flash, android-camera2, 3d-model, kudan

I am working on kudan SDK for building 3D Model Augment Reality Object with Marker, all are perfectly works fine,but when i build Camera torch on same ARActivity will stop working flash light, even it will stop working system flash torch (On/off torch from system widgets)

if in case i will extends `Activity` not `ARActivity` works perfectly fine.

Throw Run-time `Exception` when extends `ARActivity`

```
02-08 10:15:32.631 7592-7592/techno.example.com.agumentation
 W/System.err: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException:
 CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:1488: Torch for camera "0" is not
 available due to an existing camera user 02-08 10:15:32.631
 7592-7592/techno.example.com.agumentation W/System.err:     at
 android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:658)
 02-08 10:15:32.631 7592-7592/techno.example.com.agumentation
 W/System.err:     at
 android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$CameraManagerGlobal.setTorchMode(CameraManager.java:878)
 02-08 10:15:32.631 7592-7592/techno.example.com.agumentation
 W/System.err:     at
 android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.setTorchMode(CameraManager.java:51)
```

It would great to helping for solving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: @NileshRathod i have worked same thing with Camera2 class and Camera class(Deprecated form api  21) it will not work 

and yup please read question properly you got the issue what i facing right now

Comment: It will throw Exception when i Extends ARActivity

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: May be yes i wad found the solution that time but i dont remember right now, but i will send that solution soon